# How to convert 0012-03-29 to 2012-03-29 in excel?

Tags: excel, date

How to convert 0012-03-29 to 2012-03-29 in excel?

my data--> 0012-03-29 
desired output-->2012-03-29

Comment: Do you want the output as a date or as a text?

Answer (score 3):

in another cell put this formula:

```
=--REPLACE(A1,1,2,"20")
```

Then format the output cell:

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

[image]